# Why dropdown menu doesn't work in IE9?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-9

I have a dropdown menu that works fine in all browsers except **IE9**.
This is my menu http://jsfiddle.net/7Xuxv/2/ but I have no idea why this doesnt'work!

If you have Internet Explorer 10 and you want to test in IE9 you have to hitting `F12` on IE10 it should start the *Developer Tools* that allows you to emulate IE9 using the Browser Mode [[read more]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/how-can-i-test-my-web-site-in-ie6-ie7-ie8-and-ie9).

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

you problem is:

```
z-index: 1 !important;
```

remove it in your css and it works.. yet to find why